# error in removing item in qlayout pyqt4 python

Tags: python, pyqt4

The self.ui.verticalLayout.addWidget(MainWindow(self)) is working, But i receive an error when trying to remove the widget.

TypeError: QLayout.removeWidget(QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtWrapperType'

Here are the sample codes:

I have this separate .py file to create widget with qtableview

```
class MyWindow(QWidget):
    pcobject =[]
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.tableview = QTableView()
        layout.addWidget(self.tableview)
........
```

And separate .py with vertical layout to add MyWindow Class.

-Edited

```
from tableview import MyWindow

class QTEST(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.table = MyWindow
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.table))
        self.ui.gridLayout.addLayout(self.ui.verticalLayout, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.connect(self.ui.pushButton_15, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.table_view )

    def table_view(self):

        #import sip

        self.ui.verticalLayout.removeItem(self.table)

        #self.table.setParent(None)
        #sip.delete(self.table)
        #self.table = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = QTEST() 
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is that code correct? You didn't even add `self.table` to the `verticalLayout`. Why are you trying to remove it? By the way, it should be `self.table = MyWindow()`. You didn't instantiate the class.

Comment: sorry I've edited my code. I've tried your code self.table = MyWindow() but i got an error in addwidget. TypeError: QBoxLayout.addWidget(QWidget, int stretch=0, Qt.Alignment alignment=0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtWrapperType'

Comment: Umm, you tried some other thing. Look at the line you initialize `self.table`. You forgot parenthesis. It should be `MyWindow()` not just `MyWindow`.

Comment: @Avaris sorry for the late reply. It solves my problem. Can you post it as an answer so i can flag it as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTEST.table` is set to `MyWindow` class, not instance.  You need to add parenthesis: `self.table = MyWindow()`

For reference, `PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtWrapperType` is the base type of all PyQt4 classes, so if you see this error it usually means you're doing something with a class instead of an instance.